# Implementing a verbose sleep function using a chain of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, sleep, chaining

I am trying to implement a sleep function using Promises in JavaScript.

```
function sleep(ms) {

  var begin = new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Sleep function called for " + ms + " ms\n")
  });

  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    .then(() => console.log("Sleep done!" ));

}
```

and it works. But,

```
function sleep(ms) {

  var begin = new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log("Sleep function called for " + ms + " ms\n")
  });

  return begin.then(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
    .then(() => console.log("Sleep done!" ));

}
```

doesn't, rather it just hangs! What gives?

**UPDATE**: What I really want to do is write it out as a sequence of promise calls.

```
function sleep(ms) { 
    var beginAnnounce = new Promise(...);
    var goSleep = new Promise (...);
    var endAnnounce = new Promise...);

    return beginAnnounce.then(goSleep).then(endAnnounce());

}
```

Comment: The `begin` Promise never resolves because you never call its `resolve` method

Comment: So, what is the change I have to make in the 2nd code snippet?

Comment: _"...and possible a race condition"_ - Care to explain this bit of assumption?

Comment: Call the `resolve` parameter constructed in `begin`'s initial Promise

Comment: Please help with actual code.

Comment: @Andreas either be helpful or you can choose to stay out of the way!

Comment: I added `resolve()` after the `console.log` statement within the first Promise. And now it works, but erroneously. There is no wait for the sleep now...

Comment: @Andreas thanks to both the answers below, I have a better clarity of how to chain promises in ~30min - I am doubtful an additional 3 more tutorials (and 10 hours) would have helped!

Comment: @Andreas to boot, I have already completed one world-class [tutorial](http://javascript.info/promise-basics) and have purchased one [book](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Promises-Managing-Asynchronous-Code-dp-1449373216/dp/1449373216/ref=mt_paperback?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=) on Promises. And to all the downvoters, be a little bit patient!

Comment: _"...write it out as a sequence of promise calls"_ - Why? `function sleep(ms) { console.log("going to sleep..."); return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)).then(() => console.log("...finished")) }` ([example](https://jsbin.com/rucelayizu/edit?js,console))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compose two promises, you can return the second one in a callback passed to `Promise.prototype.then` of the first promise.

Have a look at the following code:

```js
const sleep = ms => () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => window.setTimeout(resolve, ms));

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => { console.log('A1');})
.then(sleep(2000))
.then(() => {console.log('A2');});

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {console.log('B1');})
.then(sleep(1000))
.then(() => {console.log('B2');});
```

The `sleep` function is a higher order function which returns another function that returns a promise. This promise is resolved in the call to `Window.setTimeout` parametrized by the `ms` passed to `sleep`.

As you can see the executions are interleaved and you will see the log output for the statement `console.log('B2')` of the second promise before the output for `console.log('A2');` of the first one.

Comment: Got it! Now, how would I pass in the `ms` value to sleep in the chain?

Comment: Not quite sure that I understand. Do you want to dynamically decide the ms value in a callback to `.then`?

Comment: Not that it matters: is the code containing a chain of three promises or two? Just for my clarity.

Comment: That's pretty simple really: you just immediately call the function returned by `sleep(ms)`: `p.then((result) => { const ms = /*calculate duration*/; return sleep(ms)();});` where `p` is your promise.

Comment: The question about the promise count is a bit tricky. Technically, `Promise.prototype.then` creates a new promise from the promise it's called on, but they are afaik resolved individually, so they should be counted individually (the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Description) also suggests this by calling `.then` a **composition** function). The _inner_ promises seem to be implicitely composed and non-promise return values are wrapped in a promise. So, each composition should consist of three promises.

Answer (score 1):

In the second snippet, you need to resolve `begin` immediately

```
var begin = new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log("Sleep function called for " + ms + " ms\n")
  resolve()
})
```

The reason it works in the first snippet is because you never rely on `begin` to finish, you just have it there to log the start. But that's not the way you want to do it. There's no point having a Promise that resolves immediately (not for your use case anyway). So you should rather do something like:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  console.log("Sleep function called for " + ms + " ms\n")

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Sleep done!")
      resolve()
    }, ms)
  })
}
```

Comment: But your code is more or less the same as mine in the 1st snippet. Yes?

Comment: I wouldn't say. There is a functional difference. You still have to resolve your returned promise. I mean, it's ok if you just want to `console.log` but then, what's the point of having promises? If you were to use `sleep` with `await` to implement a delay it wouldn't work. Another difference is that you are creating the `begin` promise which is useless

Comment: See my "update" to the OP. What I am I attempting is to build a sequence of promises (although it is an overkill here) by way of a practice. Is that even possible?

Comment: Again, it depends on how you want to use the `sleep` function. If you just want to call it and have it log "begin" -> "sleep" -> "end", then you don't need promises at all, you could just use the plain ol' `setTimeout`. Otherwise, you still wouldn't need more than one promise. You can only return one. So even if you'd want to delay the `beginAnnounce` message you could do so with just a `setTimeout`, same for `endAnnounce`

Comment: I would also suggest you go ahead and change the question title. It has nothing to do with Promise race conditions, I guess that's why you get the downvotes. I would go with something like "Help with implementing a `sleep` function" or something similar.

Comment: As suggested I have changed title, and hopefully saved the question!